# Mail as plain text in Netsuite

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

Whenever I send a mail from [netsuite](/questions/tagged/netsuite), It goes in Rich text format (HTML format).
Instead, I want to send it in Plain text format.

I tried many ways but not working. even when I send it with just as a string it goes in HTML format.
E.g.:

```
var email_subj = "Mail Subject";
var mail_content = "This goes in Body";
nlapiSendEmail(1234,'abc@gmail.com',email_subj,mail_content ,null,null,rec_MailID);
```

The above mail too goes to the recipient in Rich Text Format.

Is there a way so that it goes in Plain text format.

To know whether the mail is in rich text or plain text you can inspect the body element in browser of the recipient and you will see that there are HTML contents in the mail body.

Or if you are using Outlook: you can right click the body content and there will be option called "View Source" if you click it you will see the HTML code.

Note: in outlook if the mail is in Plain text format then "View Source" option is disabled you cannot click on it, that is what i want.

Answer (score 1):

SuiteScript 1.0 appears to wrap all email bodies in HTML tags.

SuiteScript 2.0 `N/email` module(ie: email.send() ) will format as plain text unless you include markup in the body.  Mock code:

`require(['N/email'],
    function(email) {
        function sendEmail() {
            email.send({
                author: 1234,
                recipients: 'abc@gmail.com',
                subject: 'Mail Subject',
                body: 'This goes in Body',
            });
        }
        sendEmail();
    });`

Comment: NS add a html wrapper to all emails sent from NS.  I tested them.
eg of plain text email sent through email.sendEmail method,  (body: "plaintext contents")
`<HTML><HEAD><BASE href='https://XXXXXX.app.netsuite.com/'><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"></HEAD><BODY style="font-family:Verdana,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;font-size:10pt;">plaintext contents</BODY></HTML>`